# Angular/C# null body sent for POST

Tags: c#, angular

I've trying to do a POST in Angular, which makes a call to my C# backend. One API call works fine, but the other one doesn't exactly. I'm having a hard time figuring out what's going on, but I see that when I open the Network window in my browser's DevTools, the request payload has the JSON populated just fine. But in C#/the backend, it receives a null object, and I get a 200 code/null response from the call.

I've got the following code in Angular:

**item.service.ts**

```
private readonly _api = '...'
private postOptions = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }};

public addItem(formGroup: formGroup, isInactive: boolean): Observable<Item> {
    let api = ``;

    // These require different API calls depending on the flag
    if (isInactive)
        api = `${this._api}/AddInactiveItem`;
    else
        api = `${this._api}/AddItem`; // This one is the one having issues
    const body = ItemPost.parse(formGroup.value);

    return this.http.post<Item>(api, body, this.postOptions).pipe(
        this.handle(
            "POST successful",
            "Error with POST"
        )
    );
}
```

**item-post.ts**

```
export class ItemPost {
    Name: string;
    Inactive: string;
    ...

    public static parse(obj: any): ItemPost {
        return !obj ? undefined : {
            Name: obj.name, 
            Inactive: obj.inactive,
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

My backend/POST code is in C#. Both of my POST methods are built the exact same, but with different SQL calls.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddInactiveItem([FromBody] ItemBody item)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return Json(null);

    // Do SQL call for POST here, return JSON
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddItem([FromBody] ItemBody item) // This is where I have a breakpoint and it's passing in null
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return Json(null);  // And this is where I find myself

    // Do SQL call for POST here, return JSON
}
```

**JSON Payload** (sorry, unable to get a screenshot but this is what I'm seeing):

```
{"Name":"Test", ..., "Inactive":"N"}
```

Comment: Share with us the JSON payload from dev tools.

Comment: placing the debug on the method beginning may show the item as null, try setting the debug on the opening bracket. What are the validations you set ? check modelstate.errors

Comment: @VilsadPP I placed the breakpoint at the if block, not at the very start of the method, and that's how I'm finding that it's passing null.

Comment: you are getting proper object on the first method, and getting null on the second method, right ? On the second method, is the item parameter null or does its values getting blank ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...and I feel dumb. Really dumb.

An int variable in `Item` was considered an optional int/number in the front-end for when an Item was considered active (not inactive), but in the backend, `ItemBody` didn't reflect that and was considered as just an `int` instead of `int?`. I had to dig through my `ModelState` errors through the debugger and it hinted this, but it's late at night and my mind didn't process it.

Gotta make sure all of the variable types are reflected properly in the Body object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having problem with:

```
`$(this.api}/AddInactiveItem`
```

The right syntax for template strings is:

```
`${this.api}/AddInactiveItem`
```

Comment: whats the difference? both look same to me

Comment: `${variableToParse} some string to concatenate`

You have to match the brackets.

Comment: right, opening and closing brackets are different, hard to notice at first glance :)

Comment: That was actually a typo that I made and should be fixed. I have a breakpoint set at the C# call so it's going through and still experiencing the null issue :(